# Download specific directories data with wget

Tags: download, ubuntu-14.04, wget

I am downloading data from an `'ftp'` server using `'wget'` from Ubuntu system command line. I know how to download all the directories from a specific URL. Is their any command to select and download some specific directories?

**I am using** `"wget -c -r --no-parent 'URL' --user=xx --password=xx"`

Now if I give a URL xx followed by the year say 2009, then the URL will be `xx/2009`. Now I want to download folders 100 to 365 within 2009, not the total folders `(001 to 365)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could specify the directories you want using a shell expansion:

`wget -c -r --no-parent URL/2009/{100..365} --user=xx --password=xx`

Answer (score 0):

if someone searching for these types of problem I have another solution now which is better than 

`wget -c -r --no-parent URL/2009/{100..365} --user=xx --password=xx`

This does not have any problem, but if the URL is programmed in such a way that no one is allowed to download a large amount of data at a time then the next one will do the trick

`for i in $(seq -w 144 365);do wget -r --no-parent URL/year/$i --user=XX --password=xx ; sleep 30; done`